# How to zip and transfer a folder of files in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, compression, streaming

I have a WCF service which has these endpoints:

1. A NET TCP endpoint.
2. A REST endpoint.

My service is hosted on IIS.

I have a function in the webservice where I send a folder name (would change based on input. Let say "FolderData"). The webservice looks under a master folder (Let Say D:\MasterDumps) and finds the folder "FolderData". The folder would usually contain few XML files and one Excel file. Size of the folder would vary from 1 MB to 100 MB (min & max).

What I would like is to zip this folder "FolderData" and send it over to the client. In the client I would like to extract the content and read the files and use them in my business logic.

I was looking at this [utility](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for zipping and unzipping the files. For transfer I was looking at returning a stream.

Obviously I would like to compress the data as much as I can, so that there is less data transferred over the wire.

I would like some suggestions if I am on right path. Also is there any better way to achieve this. may be a better compression approach (.NET library) and if I can apply compression while I am sending the stream over the wire.

Any suggestion(s) is appreciated. Blogs or links would help.

Comment: For the zipping part, try searching something like 'zipping files in c#'

Comment: If you're on .net >= 4.5 , there's a ZipFile class available (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider:

1. Using the streaming transfer mode in WCF (see "Streaming Data" chapter, [Streaming Message Transfer, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and updating the contract for streamed data appropriately (see [How to: Enable Streaming, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
2. Using the appropriate ZIP–compression/decompression library, which supports streaming (for example, [ZipArchive Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from .NET Framework 4.5, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), etc).

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks for the reply. I am using Streamed mode in both the endpoints. I am using DotNetZip as the library for compression. My questions were : 1. Is there a better compression library which will give me reduced compression that DotNetZip. 2. Also when I am streaming the Zip file over the WCF response can I also compress the stream as well ?

Comment: @Shankar, you are welcome! 1. It should be investigated separately. But, for example, 7-Zip can be considered ([SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)). 2. What do you mean by "compress the stream as well"?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I will have a look at Seven Zip. What I meant by Compression of stream is that when I stream and transfer the zipped up folder is there any mechanism that I can send over a compressed zip (Just to compress it further). - Girija

Comment: @Shankar, I have just updated the answer. Please take a look at the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the links I found that could probably help you.

1. [EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCF](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)
2. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)